# How to simplify multiple if else with simple for loop?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I have to check each and every condition with this repetitive if else loop. How to simplify with for loop or any other method?

```
if(color.equals("1")&&id.equals("pant"))
{

}
else if(color.equals("2")&&id.equals("pant"))
{

}
else if(color.equals("3")&&id.equals("pant"))
{

}
else if(color.equals("4")&&id.equals("pant"))
{

}
else if(color.equals("5")&&id.equals("pant"))
{

}
else if(color.equals("6")&&id.equals("pant"))
{

}


if(color.equals("1")&&id.equals("shirt"))
{

}
else if(color.equals("2")&&id.equals("shirt"))
{

}
else if(color.equals("3")&&id.equals("shirt"))
{

}
else if(color.equals("4")&&id.equals("shirt"))
{

}
else if(color.equals("5")&&id.equals("shirt"))
{

}
else if(color.equals("6")&&id.equals("shirt"))
{

}
```

Comment: What's inside the if blocks?

Comment: If no generic action is taken you can not simplify this with a for loop

Comment: If you want to use a for loop it would mean that you want to do the SAME THING for when color equals 1, 2, ... 6. If this is the case then we'll need the answer to @defaultlocale 's question first.

Comment: @defaultlocale some methods are called inside those conditions

Comment: @Ameer as other commenters pointed out it's impossible to optimize the code without seeing it first.

Comment: if there are completely different methods called then this is as simple as it can be

Comment: @Ameer Is each if/else if block calling a different method? If so, you can't simplify it too much more (see my answer for a slightly simpler way). But we might be able to help you simplify if you provide us some more information.

Comment: Even if the bodies are radically different, you can still encapsulate them inside a Command object to execute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid a lot of if else conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175805/how-to-avoid-a-lot-of-if-else-conditions)

Answer (score 1):

You can use two for loops for this purpose, 
first get a list which contains two elements that is "shirts" and "pants" something like

```
string [2] cloths = {"pants","shirts"};
```

and a variable like i and set that to 1 first

```
int i = 1;
```

and then

```
for (string cloth : cloths)
{
    for (i = 1; i < 7 ; i++)
    {
        if(color.equals(i.toString())&&id.equals(cloth))
        {
            System.out.println(i.toString()+"&"+cloth);
        }
    }
}
```

The whole idea is like this but There maybe some minor syntax errors since I didn't compile the code

Comment: The thing that this will work if OP wants to do same things, but If they are different for different conditions then it wont.

Comment: As you are saying if they want to do different things... so basically you need the if statements if they want to do different things!

Answer (score 1):

```
switch (Integer.parseInt(color))
{
    case 1:
    if (id == "pant")
    {
        // 1:pant
    }
    else if (id == "shirt")
    {
        // 1:shirt
    }
    break;

    case 2:
    if (id == "pant")
    {
        // 2:pant
    }
    else if (id == "shirt")
    {
        // 2:shirt
    }
    break;

    // etc ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use inner if statements to achieve a slightly simpler.

```
if (id.equals("pant")) {
    if (color.equals("1")) {
        //code
    }
    else if (color.equals("2")) {
        //code
    }
    //etc
}
else if (id.equals("shirt")) {
    if (color.equals("1")) {
        //code
    }
    else if (color.equals("2")) {
        //code
    }
    //etc
}
```

There may be ways to further simplify it, but we'd really need to know what is in the if blocks. For example, if you're just outputting the value, it could get really simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a common `Command` interface and encapsulate color & id into a `Key` class you can have a `Map` of `<Key, Command>` pairs.

```
public class Key {
    private final String color; // "6" as a color?  why not "blue"?
    private final String name;

    public Key(String color, String name) {
        this.color = color;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getColor() { return this.color; }
    public String getName() { return this.name; }
}

public interface Command {
    void execute(Object...args);
}

Map<Key, Command> noSwitch;
for (Key key : noSwitch.keyValues()) {
    noSwitch.get(key).execute();
}
```

Or, better yet, embed that behavior into a polymorphic `StockItem` class that knows what to do.

Yours looks like a brittle, non-object-oriented design.  You can do better.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is to create an interface:

```
interface Do {
    whatever()
}
```

Along with a bunch of implementations for whatever you do inside the different if branches.

Then have a Map of Lists to store and find them:

```
Map<String, List<Do>> dos = new HashMap();
// put lots of Do implementations in Lists and put them in the map.
```

After the setup your if monster would be reduced to:

```
dos.get(id).get(color).whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

If whats inside the braces is different you can't easily replace it with a for loop (we'd need to see whats inside the braces to be definitive). A switch statement would at least make things look nicer (assuming you use color as an int not a string of an int

```
if (id.equals("pant")){
    switch(color){ //note color should be an int, not a string of an int for this to work
         case 1:
              //whatevers in the braces
              break;
         case 2:
              //whatevers in the braces
              break;
           etc
         default:
              break;
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build a map that maps the combinations you are interested in to a function to perform.

Something like:

```
  interface Function {
    void f(); 
  }

  public void test() {
    String color = "1";
    String id = "pant";
    // Map the string to a function.
    Map<String,Function> functions = new HashMap<String,Function>();
    // As many of these as you have different processes.
    // You could name them too.
    functions.put("1|pant",new Function() {

      @Override
      public void f() {
        // What to do when we see color=1 id=pant
        System.out.println("1|pant");
      }

    });
    // Pull the function out of the map.
    Function f = functions.get(color+"|"+id);
    // If it was there.
    if ( f != null ) {
      // Do it.
      f.f();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `color`-tag as an Integer-value-`switch`:

```
switch (color){
case 1:
if (id.equals("pant"){}
else if (id.equals("shirt"){}
break;
case 2:
if (id.equals("pant"){}
else if (id.equals("shirt"){}
break;
.
.
.}
```

easiest way imo.