# Android: How to check a set of EditText for input?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Hi all I have a problem:

I have a set of 7 EditTexts and I want to check if the user have put information in them and store it in a list. I know I can go with huge number of IF statements but is there a way to do this in a simpler way and not having to write tons of code?

Comment: sure, there is a way. Assign the same handler (  TextChanged or something ) to all of those fields, cast view to EditText, get the text and populate a list, if count of list entries != 7 ( or whatever ), then values are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there're lots of alternatives. One of them is to use `HashMap` with appropriate data and `TextView`:

```
private HashMap<String, TextView> checkMap = new HashMap<String, TextView>();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    checkMap.put("DataA", textViewA);
    checkMap.put("DataB", textViewB);
    //...
}

public boolean checkFields(){
    for (Map.Entry<String, TextView> entry : checkMap.entrySet()) {
        String checkData = entry.getKey();
        TextView textView = entry.getValue();
        if(!textView.getText().toString().equals(checkData))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Other options could be found here: [How to avoid a lot of if else conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175805/how-to-avoid-a-lot-of-if-else-conditions)