# An alternative to many if-statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

So I have 3 different variables.

model which is a string and defines the
iPhone model.

storage which is a integer that defines the phones storage.

And finally price, which is an integer that defines the price of the phone.

Example:

```
model = iPhone 7
storage = 64 (GB)
price = 700 ($)
```

Another example:

```
model = iPhone 5s
storage = 16
price = 150
```

Now I want my program to notify me if I can make a good deal by buying and reselling, and my question is how do I do that in the most efficent way?

I know that I can use if statements, but is there any method to save me from writing alot diffrent if or elif statements?

Example:

```
if model == "iPhone 7" and storage == 64 and price <= 700:
print("do_something")
```

That's alot of code for just 1 model and storage option. If I would be using this method i'd have to write 29 more.

Comment: Unless you can have less specific rules than in your example, you'd have to write those if-statements. You could however find a better way to write them. What about, for instance, enclosing those information within a different class for each model, and let those classes have a method that returns `True` for any appropriate combination of storage/price?

Comment: @Denkan, kindly have a look at my `dictionary` approach and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation, I prefer dictionaries.

Create different handlers(function) that do specific task based on item and data passed. See following code :

```
# Different handlers, each takes keyword args and can work specific task
def fun1(**kwargs):
    print (kwargs)
    print("fun1")


def fun2(**kwargs):
    print("fun2")

def fun3(**kwargs):
    print("fun3")

def fun4(**kwargs):
    print("fun4")


# Example data. key is phoneModel_storage
a = {
    'iPhone1_64': {
        "storage": 64,
        "action": fun1,
        "price":1235
    },
    'iPhone1_32': {
        "storage": 64,
        "action": fun3,
        "price":1235
    },
    'iPhone2_16': {
        "storage": 16,
        "action": fun1,
        "price":1235
    },
    'iPhone3_32': {
        "storage": 32,
        "action": fun3,
        "price":1235
    },
    'iPhone4_128': {
        "storage": 128,
        "action": fun4,
        "price":1235
    },
}

model = "iPhone1"
storage = 64

data = a.get(model + "_" + str(storage), None)
if data:
    data['action'](**data)
```

Comment: the usual concerns apply about using mutable objects as defaults in function parameters.

Comment: it's just the `def foo(some_arg = something_mutable):` because the `soemthing_mutable` only gets called once, so functions that mutate it unexpectedly affect the function's global state.

Comment: I tried changing kwargs in function, it doesn't change actual data(got same data after function call)

Comment: [see this example](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1660110) and [this well-known SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Answer (score 1):

It's normal that you have to create a "decision rule" and somehow make it accessable by your program.

1-2 tips:

You might only specify the conditions when you have to act, and you do not specify the ones where you don't do anything.

You can use dicts instead "and"s like this which leads to less code:

```
deal2action = {
('iphone 7', '64', '700'):'ACT'
}
```

Usage:

```
my_deal = ('iphone 7', '64', '700')
my_action = deal2action[my_deal]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of classes to minimize the code duplication:

```
  class Phone():
    BEST_MODELS = ["IPHONE7", "IPHONE 5S", "Galaxy S3"]
    MIN_STORAGE = 100
    MAX_STORAGE = 200
    MIN_PRICE = 1000
    MAX_PRICE = 3000
    def __init__(self, model, storage, price):
        self.model = model
        self.storage = storage
        self.price = price

    def is_good_deal(self):
        return (self.model in Phone.BEST_MODELS
            and Phone.MIN_STORAGE <= self.storage <= Phone.MAX_STORAGE
            and Phone.MIN_PRICE <= self.price <= Phone.MAX_PRICE)

p1 = Phone("IPHONE7", 150, 1700)
p2 = Phone("LG G1", 150, 700)

print(p1.is_good_deal()) # True
print(p2.is_good_deal()) # False
```

And if, for example, you have a collection of Phones, you can do the following:

```
lots_of_phones = [p1, p2]

good_deal_phones = (phone for phone in lots_of_phones if phone.is_good_deal())
```

Comment: a class seems overly complex here. Something with namedtuples and a more functional approach would be better imo.

Answer (score 0):

```
if model, storage, price == "iPhone 7", 64, 700:
     print("do_something")
```

Usually I do some mini domain specific language
and define prices in a string, or csc file

```
table =
"""Iphone 7, 64, 700
Iphone 6, 34, 500"""

lines = table.split('\n)  # for wider tables use standard csv package, but or for 3 columns
dico = dict( (r[0], r[1]), r[2]) for r in line.split(', ') for line in lines))
def good_deal(model, memory, price):
    return dico.get( (model, memory), 10000000 ) > price
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about checking if particular model matches exactly data that you have, then comparing dictionaries is a way to go:

```
>>> reference = {"model": "iPhone 5s", "storage": 16, "price": 550}
>>> tested = {"model": "iPhone 5s", "storage": 16, "price": 550}
>>> reference == tested
True
```

However, this will fail if you want broader criteria, like price falling within certain range.

Then, instead of writing 29 `if`s, you can store reference dictionaries in list and check if your tested model is in that list with simplest

```
tested in reference_list:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is perfect for a hashmap (dict) with something like tuples or preferably namedtuples.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Phone = namedtuple("Phone", "model storage price")

funcmap = {Phone("iPhone 7", 64, 700): \
             lambda p: print("Do something to ", p),
           Phone(...):  # etc
             ...,
           ... }

phone = Phone("iPhone 7", 64, 700)
f = funcmap[phone]  # maybe funcmap.get(phone, lambda _: None) in case it's new?
f(phone)
```

That said a decision-making algorithm seems better.

```
def is_good_deal(phone: Phone) -> (bool, None):
    value_dict = {Phone("iPhone 7", 64, 700): 600,
                  ...}
    try:
        return phone.value < value_dict[phone]
    except KeyError:
        # phone isn't in value_dict
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining methods to print something

```
def method1():
    print "Yippee I have best iPhone 7 :)"

def method2():
    print "Oh! still it is an iPhone 7"

def method3():
    print "Yeah! I have best iPhone 5 :)"

def method4():
    print "Oh! base iPhone 5"
```

Dictionary for if-else

```
stuff = {'iPhone 7' : {'64GB' : { '$700' : method1}, '32GB' : { '$500' : method2}}, 'iPhone 5' : {'32GB' : { '$250' : method3}, '16GB' : { '$150' : method4}}}
```

Access the statements like and add exception handling as needed

```
stuff['iPhone 7']['64GB']['$700']()
```

[image]

Reference [How to avoid a lot of if else conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175805/how-to-avoid-a-lot-of-if-else-conditions)

Answer (score 0):

There are soooo many answers here, but still none accepted, so I will put together another one:

```
# Prepare a list of what you know will be good deals: 
dctGoodDeals = {}
dctGoodDeals[('iPhone 7',  64)] = 700
dctGoodDeals[('iPhone 5s', 16)] = 150

# You have got at that point in your code from somewhere: 
model = 'iPhone 7'; storage=64; price=500
# model = 'iPhone S'; storage=64; price=500
```

> # so you can put at that point into your code following:
>   
>       `try: 
>           if (price <= dctGoodDeals[(model, storage)]): 
>               print("do something")
>       except:
>           print("not yet in dctGoodDeals:", model, "with", storage, "GB")`

This way you get all the printouts of what to do and save some typing effort of writing all the `if`s.