# Avoid simple if/else conditions

Tags: java

In my program, I need to check if a variable equals 1, 2 or 3 and depending on the result, perform a different method:

```
if (phase.equals("1")) {
    PhaseOne.performPhase(inputParser.getSource(), inputParser.getTarget());
} else if (phase.equals("2")) {
    PhaseTwo.performPhase(inputParser.getSource(), inputParser.getTarget());
} else {
    PhaseThree.performPhase(inputParser.getSource(), inputParser.getTarget());
}
```

This code is so simple and basic but I really don't like it. Of course I could use switch conditions but it would, in my humble opinion, just display the same basic function in a different way.

My question is: is there a way to implement the function in an elegant and expandable way?

FYI, I already red [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175805/how-to-avoid-a-lot-of-if-else-conditions) post but I did not find an answer which fits to my question.

Comment: Judging by the fact that your classes are named `Phase` I would suggest the State pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern

Comment: Are those static methods? Otherwise you can just create a `Map<String, Phase> phases` and call `phases.get("1").performPhase()`.

Comment: You can use [a switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) in the case of strings. `switch(phase) case "1": /*something*/; break; case "2" ...`

Comment: You should use case instead of if, is safer because it avoids 2 situations with the same condition. Case does not alow 2 cases with the same value.

Comment: Related: [Replacing if else statement with pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049094/replacing-if-else-statement-with-pattern)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my opinion, the accepted answer on your linked question fits you very well. Store references to the functions in the map:

```
Map<String,BiConsumer<T,U>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("1",PhaseOne::performPhase);
map.put("2",PhaseTwo::performPhase);
map.put("3",PhaseThree::performPhase);
map.get(phase).accept(inputParser.getSource(), inputParser.getTarget());
```

Replace `T` and `U` by the types of `inputParser.getSource()` and `inputParser.getTarget()`.

With this approach, the `Phase…` classes don't need a common superclass or interface.

Answer (score 2):

If your `PhaseOne`/`PhaseTwo`/`PhaseThree` classes all implement the same interface (let's say `Phase`), and the method `performPhase` is defined on the interface you could do the following:

```
final Phase targetPhase;
switch(phase) {
    case "1": targetPhase = myInstanceOfPhaseOne; break;
    case "2": targetPhase = myInstanceOfPhaseTwo; break;
    case "3": targetPhase = myInstanceOfPhaseThree; break;
    default: throw new IllegalStateException("Unrecognised phase "+phase);
}
targetPhase.performPhase(inputParser.getSource(), inputParser.getTarget()));
```

Comment: There are no instances. They're static methods.

Comment: @Michael Not necessarily. OP might also just be violating naming conventions.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Seems unlikely given that he's used the correct naming conventions everywhere else.

Comment: To be honest, this was more of a suggestion rather than a question :)

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to create a Class for each Phase and an IPhase Interface for them to implement.
Create a `List<IPhase>` with all your different Phase instances.
Run a loop and if the id matches, execute the overwritten method.

```
public interface IPhase {
    public void performPhase();
    public String getId();
}

for (IPhase phase : phasesList){
    if (phase.equals(phase.getId())){
        phase.performPhase();
        // either break or continue the loop
    }
}
```